# Who is stronger, Asta or Noelle Silva?

Tags: black-clover

I just want to know: who is stronger? Based out of these two since they are in the league of learning new type of control magic. That's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn’t watch the captain Yami and Asta fighting with Dante (one of the most powerful out of the Dark Triad), don’t read this becuse this has some spoilers. This also has spoilers about The queen of the heart kingdom, Noelle, and the bird on astas head vs Megicula (the weakest one of Dark Triad)

Alright so,

Asta and captain yami are both arcane stage (the highest level).
The queen of the heart kingdom is arcane stage, as well as Noelle and Secre (the bird that is always on Astas head) Noelle, The bird, and the queen of the heart kingdom all lost the battle against Megicula even when Megicula was one of the weakest one of the dark triad since she can only go up to 70%

Asta and Captain Yami won the battle against Dante. As I have said before, Dante is one of the strongest of the dark triad because him and Zenon can go up to 80%.  I don’t know how much Astas devil possessed hand him, but remember that even when Noelle, the queen of of the heart kingdom, and the bird were all arcane stage which means that they have the equal power of asta and captain Yami, they all still lost to Migicula which in turn was one of the weakest of the dark triad. Which leads me to think that Asta is clearly stronger than Noelle.

You can see all of this in the black clover Manga/anime.
Source where you can get the manga: https://www.viz.com/black-clover

If you are a big anime fan go here so that you can see the black clover anime. You just need to tap on a website you would like to watch it in. Then when you get into the website search up black clover and then you can enjoy the black clover anime: https://www.viz.com/watch/streaming